# Renaming ending of all files in a folder and subfolder (*.log to *.txt)

Tags: vb.net, file-rename

Is it possible to rename all the files in a folder and subfolder with a simple program, using vb.NET
I'm quite green and not sure if this is even possible.

D:\Main\   <--- there are 10 Files. 
D:\Main\Sub\  <--- there are some more files
...

The files has always the ending "log" like "this is a test.log" or "this_is_the_second.log". All the files-ending rename to "txt" like "this is a test.txt" or "this_is_the_second.txt".

I tried allready this code, but it doesn´t work :

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    renameFilesInFolder()
End Sub
Private Sub renameFilesInFolder()
    Dim sourcePath As String = "D:\Main"
    Dim searchPattern As String = "*.log"
    For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        File.Move(Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName), Path.Combine(sourcePath, ".txt"))

    Next
End Sub
```

Please help me!?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub RenameFilesInFolder()
    Dim sourcePath As String = "D:\Main"
    Dim searchPattern As String = "*.log"

    For Each currentFilePath As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim newFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(currentFilePath, ".txt")

        File.Move(currentFilePath, newFilePath)
    Next
End Sub
```

The `GetFiles` method gets the full file path, not just the name. `Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName)` would result in values like *"D:\MainD:\Main\Sub\test.log"* while `Path.Combine(sourcePath, ".txt")` would have resulted in the value *"D:\Main.txt"* every time.